# How to stop form submitting if form is not validated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I am validating form using jquery but the issue is when the form is validated, irrespective of whether the form is validated or not it gets submitted. I want 
when the form is validated if there is some error (eg. empty field) then the form must not get submitted. Please help to solve my issue.

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#login_user").validate({
              rules: {
                txtemail: {
                  required: true
                },
                txtpassword: {
                  required: true
                }
              },
              messages: {
                txtemail: {
                  required: "Please enter Username or Email Address"
                },
                txtpassword: {
                  required: "Please enter Password"
                }
              }
      });
    });
    </script>

    <form name="login_user" id="login_user" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="txtemail" type="text" placeholder="Username"/> 
    <input name="txtpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>  
    <a id="submit" onclick='document.forms["login_user"].submit(); return false;'>Login</a>

    </body>
```

Comment: [The HTML5 placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: @vinayakj What happen on browsers which don't support placeholder attribute?  http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
 <a id="submit" onclick='document.forms["login_user"].submit(); return false;'>Login</a>
```

to

```
 <input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

and close form tag

```
<form name="login_user" id="login_user" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input name="txtemail" type="text" placeholder="Username"/> 
    <input name="txtpassword" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>  
    <input type="submit"  value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

Add `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#login_user').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //do validation and if validation passes
      $('#login_user').submit();
  });
});
```

Comment: That will have no effect, since the form is never submitted by the user (only by JavaScript, which doesn't trigger the submit event). Even if that wasn't the case, it would *always* prevent the form from submitting, not only if validation failed. Additionally, it changes the code that binds a submit handler for validation to code that binds a submit handler to bind a submit handler for validation … which is just awful and useless.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I was trying to answer like so.

Comment: After your edit, it still doesn't solve the original problem (which is that the submit event never fires in the first place) and expects the OP to rewrite their validation code from scratch instead of using the library they already have.